# redirecting to non-https resource error with HTTPClient in Ruby

Tags: ruby, httpclient

When I use `content = client.get_content(lasturl)` I'm getting this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:664:in `default_redirect_uri_callback': redirecting to non-https resource (HTTPClient::BadResponseError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:962:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:962:in `follow_redirect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:594:in `get_content'
    from he_sender.rb:332:in `<main>'
```

URL I want to get is https and I already disabled SSL check:

```
client.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

How I can solve such problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting from `https` to `http` is bad, and HTTPClient protects you against that.

If you *really* want to allow for that, and eliminate the exception, you can override [`redirect_uri_callback`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/h/httpclient-xaop-2.1.6/HTTPClient.html#method-i-redirect_uri_callback-3D):

```
client.redirect_uri_callback = ->(uri, res) {
  res.header['location'][0]
}
```